# Cambiar idioma tooltip VScode

Tags: vscode, idioma, tooltip

Estoy buscando, si existe, la opción de **cambiar el idioma** a las sugerencias que te da VSCode al dejar el mouse encima de una función o cuando te auto completa parte del código (tooltip).
Uso la extensión de Microsoft IntelliCode.

He visto que estos recuadros se pueden desactivar, pero no he encontrado nada acerca del idioma.

Os dejo un ejemplo de lo que me refiero:

[image: Ejemplo tooltip]

Gracias!

Comment: Los tooltips que no son de vscode, sino de extensiones no suelen tener soporte para cambio de idioma. No sé que extensión usas pero puedes darle un vistazo a sus configuraciones, tal vez tenga alguna opción para cambiarlo. Otra opción puede ser modificar manualmente la extensión y cambiar los tooltips uno por uno.

Comment: He añadido la extensión que uso en VSCode. 
Gracias Mateo.

Comment: Creo que no se puede cambiar el idioma de los tooltips de esa extensión. Un Tooltip te muestra la documentación de cada cosa que se encuentre documentada. En el caso de tus creaciones puedes decidir en qué idioma hacerlo de la manera que corresponde. Por ejemplo en C# se usan comentarios XML especiales; en Java se usa JavaDoc; en JavaScript, JSDoc y así.

Comment: Entiendo, no lo sabía. Muchas gracias por la aclaración!